# Admin edit view - populate fields by parameter

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is there a way to prepopulate `admin add form` by parameters?
Using the usual book-publisher example, I am trying to establish a link on the publisher edit page to directly add books:

from django.db import models

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
```

I would like to adjust my Publisher model by a link to add a book directly adding the following link to my publisher model:

```
class PublisherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def add_book_link(self, instance):
        url = reverse('admin:myapp_book_add')
        return mark_safe(u'<a href="{u}">Add</a>'.format(u=url))

    add_book_link.short_description = _("New Book")

    readonly_fields = ['add_book_link',]
```

1. How can I pass an argument (the publisher id) to the `add` page?
2. How can I change the Publisher field on the `add_book` page?

I am aware of inlines, but I cannot user them in my case. I also looked at `prepopulated_fields` but those can only read from existing fields.

Comment: You will need to override your change_form template: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not hard. The add form is instantiated using `request.GET` to set initial values, so all you need to do is put the appropriate value into your URL:

```
def add_book_link(self, instance):
    if instance.id:
        url = '%s?publisher=%d' % (reverse('admin:myapp_book_add'), instance.id)
    else:
        url = reverse('admin:myapp_book_add')
    return mark_safe(u'<a href="{u}">Add</a>'.format(u=url))
```

I'm generally in the habit of setting `allow_tags` rather than using `mark_safe` for admin fields.